# How to convert string to string array using java

Tags: java, arrays

```
wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com,kavindapathum@gmail.com,pathum123@gmail.com,danushka@gmail.com
```

I want to convert above string value as below using java.

```
["wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com","kavindapathum@gmail.com","pathum123@gmail.com,"danushka@gmail.com"]
```

How I create it.

Comment: [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: java gives splitmethod and you can get array based on regex.

Comment: public class StringSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com,kavindapathum@gmail.com,pathum123@gmail.com,danushka@gmail.com";
        //for(String curLine:input)
        String[] parts = input.split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
            System.out.println(parts[i]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Gaurav mahindra, dont post code over here, answer it

Comment: @khAn: I missed to answer it by few seconds. It was marked duplicate. That's why.

Comment: oops, no worries i thought you are not aware of that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `Split()` method of `String` class or `StringTokenizer` class to split String.

see below code.

```
package naveed.practice;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com,kavindapathum@gmail.com,pathum123@gmail.com,danushka@gmail.com";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split(",")));
    //OR
    StringTokenizer s1= new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
    while(s1.hasMoreElements())
    {
        System.out.println(s1.nextElement());
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
[wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com, kavindapathum@gmail.com, pathum123@gmail.com, 

danushka@gmail.com]
wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com
kavindapathum@gmail.com
pathum123@gmail.com
danushka@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="wpraneethmadusanka@gmail.com,kavindapathum@gmail.com,pathum123@gmail.com,danushka@gmail.com";
String[] arr= s.split(",");
```